# Where to ask why a file can be a valid JPG and RAR simultaneously?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My question is regarding a hidden file inside another file. However, it is not a specific problem I have about programming (that discards StackOverflow, I think) but instead a "How does it work?" question.

My question is:

> I know I can build a .rar file with regular method or programs, and append it to an image by using a command such as `cat img.jpg myfile.rar > img.jpg` and when opening the image, the image will be displayed as before. But I can also open the image with WinRAR or a software alike (like `unrar e img.jpg`). How is possible that the rar file is recognized inside the jpg image, instead of rejected as not being an appropriate file format?

But, seriously, I cannot figure in which site is it appropriate to ask it (perhaps the question even exists in such site and I am not aware of it, because I don't know the appropriate site from start).

Where can I ask this question?

Comment: The closest I can think off would be programmers.se but I doubt if they take this question as [they have very strict rules](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-programmers-se-a-guide-for-stack-overflow) and non-regulars most often get it wrong, including me. You could check in their chat room first to see what they think.

Comment: @rene at Programmers it will likely fail not by topicality but by scope ([Why is research important?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6559/31260)). It's "explain me jpg format specification" in disguise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a general computer question, not specific to any operating system, not security-related, not programming-related.  I suggest [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Will check the scope

Comment: Actually, check out [this question](https://superuser.com/q/705126/31983) before you ask.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted. I am upvoting since it seems to be well-received in such site. If it is actually well received, you will have my acceptance (my question is slightly different to the one you linked).